# Переключатель для всех кнопок

Tags: javascript

Всем привет ! Сделала переключатель состояния кнопки с помощью JS. Но оно работает почему-то только для первой кнопки, а для остальных нет. Пробовала перебирать let gardenButtons с помощью forEach и далее запускать функцию с toggle, но где-то допускаю ошибку и ничего не получается. Помогите пожалуйста.

```html
<div class="button-block-about">
  <form action="#">
    <button class="service-butt" id="0">Gardens</button>
  </form>
  <form action="#">
    <button class="service-butt" id="1">Lawn</button>
  </form>
  <form action="#">
    <button class="service-butt" id="2">Planting</button>
  </form>
</div
```

```css
.service-butt{
  background-color: transparent;
}
    
.serviceButtAct{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```js
let gardenButtons = document.querySelector('.service-butt');
    
let handleClick = (event) => {
  gardenButtons.classList.toggle('serviceButtAct')
}
    
gardenButtons.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

Comment: `querySelector` возвращает первый найденный элемент. Воспользуйтесь `querySelectorAll`, он отберет все элементы и вернет коллекцию. Далее циклом вешайте события на элементы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен не **querySelector**, а **querySelectorAll**. Так вы получите [коллекцию узлов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList) по заданному селектору. Потом с помощью цикла нужно пройтись по коллекции через `.forEach` (подобно массиву) и навесить слушатели событий:

```js
const gardenButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.service-butt');
gardenButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.classList.toggle('serviceButtAct');
  })
})
```

К слову, лучше используйте const вместо let, если значение не меняется.

Comment: ***Так вы получите массив всех html-элементов...*** - не получите массив, получите коллекцию узел элементов (`NodeListOf<Element>`). Разница в них большая.

Comment: @eccs0103 Точно. Спасибо, поправил

Comment: Спасибо большое @SiRanWeb ! Перед этим использовала querySelectorAll, но из-за неверного кода - не работал, а вот почему-то querySelector дал результат на одну кнопку